# Add more data to a step "copy rows to result"

Tags: pentaho, etl, kettle

I'm doing a transformation in kettle and I need to send data to another transformation, for this use a step "copy rows to result", but this step I do half the processing and need to add more data to the end of the transformation, as might do?.

Greetings and thanks

EDIT 24-06-2014

This image is the example of my transformation:

[image]

Comment: Your setup is not quite clear to me. How many transformations do your have in total? What do you mean by "add more data"? Is it a union? Or a join? Could you include a screen shot of your job setup?

Comment: Marcus, thanks for your answer, include a link to the image

Comment: Have you tried to combine your outputs using the *Combine streams* component before sending them to "Copy results"? By the way: what is the actual problem currently? What is the current result and what is the expected result?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you need to make sure when merging the results from multiple streams in Kettle is that the columns from both hops to `Copia Filas` (`Copy rows to result` in the English version) are completely identical, meaning:

1. The number of columns sent to the final step is equal;
2. The column types are completely identical;
3. The column names are completely identical;

Kettle should alert if otherwise. 
If this is not the issue, you should check that the second stream in the data distribution actually generates the data you want to merge into the final step of the transformation, depending on what you'd like to do there.

Use the preview and debug options, as well as the `right click` (on a step) ==> `Show output fields` in Kettle to make sure all of the above are happening.

I hope this helps a bit.